# How to bring the values of while loop in the Response in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, while-loop, response

I am trying to calculate the counts of each day sales/orders made in the last 30 (7 days for now).

My view look like this.

```
class DashboardView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        count_1 = Order.objects.filter(order_items__item__merchant=self.kwargs['pk']).count() 
      

        startdate_1 = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1)
        enddate_1 = startdate_1 + timedelta(days=1)

        startdate_2 = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=2)
        enddate_2 = startdate_2 + timedelta(days=1)

        startdate_3 = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=3)
        enddate_3 = startdate_3 + timedelta(days=1)       
...............................#upto 30 days

        count_8 = Order.objects.filter(order_items__item__merchant=self.kwargs['pk'],
                                       ordered_date__range=[startdate_1, enddate_1]).count()
        count_9 = Order.objects.filter(order_items__item__merchant=self.kwargs['pk'],
                                       ordered_date__range=[startdate_2, enddate_2]).count()
        count_10 = Order.objects.filter(order_items__item__merchant=self.kwargs['pk'],
                                       ordered_date__range=[startdate_3, enddate_3]).count()
          ..................#upto 30 days     
        return Response(
            {'active_users_now': count_2,
             
              'total_orders_one_day_ago': count_8,
             'total_orders_two_days_ago': count_9,
             'total_orders_three_days_ago': count_10,
             
             #"total_orders_i_days_ago":count_i,


             },
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**What I want is to use loop instead of writing such long codes for 30 days.**

**Here is what I have tried: This is just a logic not actual code for python**

```
i = 1
        while (i<=7):
            startdate[i] = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=i)
            enddate[i] = startdate[i] + timedelta(days=1)

            count[i] = Order.objects.filter(order_items__item__merchant=self.kwargs['pk'],
                                           ordered_date__range=[startdate[i], enddate[i]]).count()

            i+= i


return Response(

                {i:count[i],},
                status=status.HTTP_200_OK
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked perfectly.

```
    count = []
        dates_count = []

        i=1
        while (i <= 31):
            startdate = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=i)
            enddate = startdate + timedelta(days=1)

            counts = Order.objects.filter(order_items__item__merchant=self.kwargs['pk'],
                                               ordered_date__range=[startdate, enddate]).count()

            count.append(counts)
            enddate = enddate.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
            dates_count.append(enddate)
            i += 1

        dictionary = dict(zip(dates_count, count))

return Response(
            {'active_users_now': count_2,
             

             'orders_with_dates':dictionary

             },
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```